# How can i add an item to a listbox?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, wysiwyg, tinymce-4

I am still at upgrading tinymce version 3 to version 4.

The problem i have is with the usage of the toolbar ui.
I am able to create a listbox with several entries, but i do not know how to add listbox elements after the listbox has been created.
With tinymce3 it was easy to add a list item to a list even after creation of that list.
I do not know how to achieve this with tinymce 4.

What do i need to do? Any suggestions?

Here the code i use to create the listbox:

```
        editor.addButton('my_listbox', {
            type: 'listbox',
            text: 'my_listbox_desc',
            icon: false,
            onselect: function(e) {
                editor.insertContent(this.value());
            },
            values:[
                {text: 'Menu item 1', value: 'Some text 1'},
                {text: 'Menu item 2', value: 'Some text 2'},
                {text: 'Menu item 3', value: 'Some text 3'}
            ],
            onPostRender: function() {
                // Select the third item by default
                editor.irstyle_control = this;
                this.value('Some text 3');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue... After visiting many topics on their forum, I came to write something like this

```
  tinymce.PluginManager.add('sampleWithEditable', function(ed, url) {

    var me=this, dynamicallyEditable;

   function getValues() {
  return ed.settings.myKeyValueList;
   }
ed.addButton('my_listbox', {
        type: 'listbox',
        text: 'my_listbox_desc',
        icon: false,
        onselect: function(e) {
            ed.insertContent(this.value());
        },
        values:[
            {text: 'Menu item 1', value: 'Some text 1'},
            {text: 'Menu item 2', value: 'Some text 2'},
            {text: 'Menu item 3', value: 'Some text 3'}
        ],
        onPostRender: function() {
            // Select the third item by default
            ed.irstyle_control = this;
            this.value('Some text 3');

            dynamicallyEditable=this
        }});

   me.refresh = function() {
  if(dynamicallyEditable.dynamicallyAdded){
     dynamicallyEditable.dynamicallyAdded.remove();
     dynamicallyEditable.dynamicallyAdded = null;
      }

      dynamicallyEditable.settings.values =     dynamicallyEditable.settings.dynamicallyAdded = getValues();
   };

    }
```

Then From the ajax success method

```
   tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.myKeyValueList = [{text: 'text_here', value: 'value_there'}]; 
   tinyMCE.activeEditor.plugins.sampleWithEditable.refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunatly, i am not able to make it work. I created a tinymce fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/LWdaab/1 .Could you please have a look and tell me what is wrong?